# Copying files with filtering out same files

Tags: windows-7, file-comparison

I'm having this problem. I copied bunch of files from one disk to another (around 200gb). Some files in the process didn't copy, mostly because the name was to long.

So, I'm looking for a tool that can find, correct (or let me correct), and copy remaining files. Is there any out of the box tools out there?

Answer (score -1):

I had a very similar problem. On windows I used [this](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php) to batch rename and copy files.

The tool is called Bulk Rename Utility. It basically lets you use Regex to match multiple files and rename them according to a pattern. It also allows for file name trimming which sounds like exactly what you need. There are also other similar tools out there that will allow you do to same and a quick Google search will reveal most of them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved. If the link provided goes stale your answer becomes worthless.

Comment: @suspectus Please see my edit. The answer he's looking for is a link to a tool and can't be improved on more than this.

Comment: Sry, not really what I'm looking for. Renaming is not the problem, finding the uncopied files is...